# PPPOE and VPN on same router

Tags: networking, vpn, dd-wrt, openwrt, pppoe

I have a TP-Link WR841n v11 router. I want to connect to VPN (I'm using privateinternetaccess) because my ISP blocks alot of website but I also need to dial PPPoE (ISP) through this router.

Topo:

```
Internet --- Modem (bridge mode) ---  WR841n --- LAN
                                         |  
                                         |  
                                         |  
                                        VPN
```

I don't think it's possible with the stock TP-Link firmware because both PPPOE and PPTP/L2TP are in WAN category and you can only choose one. Is it possible with custom firmware like DD-WRT or OpenWRT?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is possible. In OpenWrt you *can* configure two different WANs (i.e., WAN-VPN and WAN-PPPoE). The problem would be to set up some form of load balancing in such a way that requests for sites blocked by your ISP on WAN-PPPoE would automatically be re-routed to the other WAN (to WAN-VPN).

I think there is more than one WAN load balancing package for OpenWrt. What remains to be seen is if one of them can be configured to do what you need. If you get no other answer here, I would suggest you try posting a question on the OpenWrt/LEDE forums.